# Как правильно написать?

Tags: орфография

"С каждым днем усложняются решения, увеличивается бюджет, появляются новые услуги**, -** все это приводит к необходимости..."
Правильно ли ставятся запятая и тире в данном случае?

Comment: @galina, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, так как запятая при однородных членах - это разделительный знак, т.е. ставится между однородными членами.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, это не орфография, а пунктуация. Во-вторых, предложение опять не закончено.

Comment: С каждым днем усложняются решения, увеличивается ИТ-бюджет и появляются новые услуги, - все это приводит к необходимости оценки и оптимизации информационной инфраструктуры. 
Это - полное предложение. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение. Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна.~~~

Comment: @behemothus, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.